invalid_grant" error on a specific server oAuth2
I had set Token timeout and logintimeout in web.config like below
<add key="Token-TimeOut" value="1" />
<add key="Login-TimeOut" value="60" />

the below api call is working when I execute it before 1 minute but after token timeout it is not working but it should work as I want to fetch new token after every minute and this is working fine everywhere except on a live server of one of our client (working on UAT of that client)
refresh_token = Utils.getRefreshToken()
var DATA = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + refresh_token + "&client_id=";

$.ajax({
    url: Utils.getWebApiUrl() + "/token",
    method: "POST",
    data: DATA,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",  // Add this line
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);  // Log successful response
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.error("Error: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);  // Log detailed error information
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);  // Check server response
});

I am getting invalid grant error and both the copies (Live and UAT) are same, all the global variables are correct and it is working for Grant_type password but not for refreshToken, how can I fix this?

What oauth2 server are you using and what's the configuration?
